# Excel - Assign Values to Strings and Calculate a Total

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of headings with job 'sizes' assigned to them :

```
Project_Name    Heading1    Heading2    Heading3    Heading4   Heading5    Heading6
Project1        Large                   Small
Project2                    X-Large                 X-Large
Project3                                                                   Small
Project4        Small
Project5                                                       Medium
```

The sizes correspond to number of days :
**Small** = 5
**Medium** - 10
**Large** = 20
**X-Large** = 30

I want to add a 'Total Days' column that will calculate the running total of the days depending on what appears on each row. Expected output would look something like :

```
Project Name    Total     Heading1    Heading2    Heading3    Heading4   Heading5    Heading6
Project1        25        Large                   Small
Project2        60                    X-Large                 X-Large
Project3        5                                                        Small
Project4        5         Small
Project5        10                                            Medium
```

As above, sometimes each row will have data against more than one heading.

Is there any way to achieve this without having a whole host of filter columns? (Not against this, but its the only way I can think!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create lookup table, you can use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C11:H11=$J$11:$J$14)*$K$11:$K$14)
```

[image]

if not, use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:H2={"S","M","L","XL"})*{5,10,20,30})
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, basic. Thank you very much! I have went with the first option and added a hidden 'config' tab to hold the lookup table :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula like this and reference an area with their values:

=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$G$1:$H$5,2,FALSE),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$G$1:$H$5,2,FALSE),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,$G$1:$H$5,2,FALSE),0))

[image]